# How to use custom SSO login authentication in Confluence?

Tags: soap, single-sign-on, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I currently got a task to enable SSO for Confluence and JIRA. As of now, they have their own user database which sits in SQL. I've read so many articles that we can connect Confluence with **Active Directory** and **LDAP** and so on.

Unfortunately, we have a third-party which hosts our Active Directory on Azure and  we are ***not permitted*** to access it but only via **SOAP**!

So, now I am researching on how to enable users to login using that SOAP so that users don't need to login to confluence if they have been authenticated via SOAP already. We also don't want to use CROWD as we don't have AD on our server.

We are in .NET environment so do you have any suggestions in terms of confirming that it is doable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this add-on?
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.resolution.atlasplugins.samlsso.Jira/server/overview

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.resolution.atlasplugins.samlsso.Confluence/server/overview

It has a cost, but it supports Azure AD. We installed it for Confluence and Jira and worked ok.

Comment: I looked into these but the problem is we don't have access to integrate it with our Activery directory. We only have access to authenticate users via their SOAP API. These plug-ins you offered, could they work without enabling Azure Active Directory but custom SOAP API Authentication?